# Retrieving a public accounts followers?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to retrieve a list of usernames from some sort of GET statement of a public account?

I've seen many websites reference followers of a public account, but after reading through the IG API Documentation it says the account needs to be authenticated.

What other ways of retrieving an public accounts followers are there?

Thanks, and I apologize if any of my terminology isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethings without authentication.

some endpoints don't require a access_token.
for example:

GET/users/user-id

if you pass any valid id you will receive something like that:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
    "counts": {
        "media": 1320,
        "follows": 420,
        "followed_by": 3410
    }
}
```

and to retrieve a list of usernames you can you send a request to GET/users/search https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search
It also doesn't required a access_token

if you already have the user-id and would like to retrieve followers and following you can do it without a access_token too
just send a request to

```
GET /users/user-id/follows
```

and/or

```
GET /users/user-id/followed-by
```

you also can test your request on this website: https://apigee.com/console/instagram

enjoy :)